# Is it a programmatic way to get SQL keywords (reserved words)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, keyword, reserved-words

I need to validate the **Name** of a SQL column, which is created programmatically...

There whould be 2 validation rules:

1. The **Name** shouldn't be a C# keyword
2. The **Name** shouldn't be a SQL keyword *(SQL Server 2008 R2)*

---

**The solution for 1st rule it's nice:**

The **CSharpCodeProvider** class has the **IsValidIdentifier** method which makes the implementation of validation easy.

(ex:

```
string myColumnName = "blabla";
var isValid = _cSharpCodeProvider.IsValidIdentifier(myColumnName);
```

)

---

**The solution for 2nd rule it's a litle verbose:**

The only way I found doing google searches is to take the keywords from [MSDN - Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL) SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

To build a  string[] property which will return all these keywords...

(ex:

```
public static class SqlReservedKeywords {

     public static string[] SqlServerReservedKeywords {
        get { return SqlServerKeywords; }
     }

     private static readonly string[] SqlServerKeywords = new[] { 
        "ADD","EXISTS","PRECISION",   

    //. . .

        "EXEC","PIVOT","WITH",
        "EXECUTE","PLAN","WRITETEXT"
     };
}
```

//External code

```
var isValid = SqlReservedKeywords.SqlServerReservedKeywords.Contains(myColumnName);
```

)

---

Can you advice me about implementantion of 2nd validation rule. 
Is it a good practice? 
Maybe it exist another way to implement which i didn't found by googling...

Comment: I am sure you can bypass reserved words if you add brackets around your field.

Comment: @Sam1 I don't want to allow to bypass these keywords. Thanks

Comment: @Sam +1 Also ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Trying to forbid a column name from being any particular word seems like a mistake. SQL has quoting mechanisms for a reason; why do you not want to use them?

Comment: Since you asked, I think that avoiding sql keywords in a database column name is a better practice than avoiding c# keywords.  Others have mentioned that keywords can be handled, but I'd rather not have to.

Comment: Minor aside, but SqlReservedKeywords.SqlServerReservedKeywords[4] = "aaa"; is allowed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is a function you can call for C#, the real question is how to do the lookup for SQL Reserved words.  The way you implemented look up here is NOT the most efficient C#.  You should use a HashSet -- quick untested code example follows:

```
public static class SqlReservedKeywords {

   public bool isReserved(string in)
   {
      return SqlServerKeywords.Contains(in.ToUpper());
   }

   private static HashSet<string> SqlServerKeywords = new HashSet<string>();

   static SqlReservedKeywords() 
   {
      SqlServerKeywords.Add("ADD");
      SqlServerKeywords.Add("EXISTS");
      SqlServerKeywords.Add("PRECISION");

   //. . .

      SqlServerKeywords.Add("EXEC");
      SqlServerKeywords.Add("PIVOT");
      SqlServerKeywords.Add("WITH");
      SqlServerKeywords.Add("EXECUTE");
      SqlServerKeywords.Add("PLAN");
      SqlServerKeywords.Add("WRITETEXT");
   }   
}
```

Here is a nice article (by @theburningmonk) showing how fast HashSet is when using Contains

(For those that don't want to click, HashSet is zero)

http://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/hashset-vs-list-vs-dictionary/

Answer (score 4):

Reserved words are a moving target. If the dbms doesn't expose them through a public interface, there isn't usually a good programmatic way to get to them.

If you don't want to guard them with brackets, you risk incorporating symbols that are not reserved in your currently used version of SQL Server, but *are* reserved in some future version.

I think your best bet is to use the quoting mechanism your dbms provides, since it's designed to deal with exactly this problem. For SQL Server, that means square brackets.

Comment: @Hogan by my reckoning, [SQL Server 2012 reserved keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) has five more entries than [SQL Server 2008 R2 reserved keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and that's just one version different.

Comment: @Hogan [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) has 696 reserved words, [SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(v=sql.80).aspx) had 605 (if I didn't make any copy/paste errors). So that's 91 new words, an increase of about 15%.

Comment: This is SQL Server guys, not SQL -- but point taken -- it will change.

Comment: Well, reserved words in SQL itself are liable to change with every publication of a new standard. New features usually mean new reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the approach looks correct. Getting keywords for any given language involves a (hopefully small) bit of trial and error due to anything undocumented but the main source is always the language specification itself. I don't know of any languages that come with their own validators but that's not to say they don't exist.

Visual Studio itself has a set of xml files that help it do the validation for any given language. If you were developing an IDE, you might have a table that looked something like;

```
Keyword     | MatchWithRegEx | Color
------------+----------------+---------
for         | \wfor          | #FF0000
```

...you get the idea. In your case, you just want to filter out possible problem keywords so that they don't throw an exception. Allowing an exception to be thrown and catching and handling it specifically *is* a valid methodology albeit not a very clean one.

As for your case, the only real tweak I'd make is not having the list of keywords buried into the program at compile time but instead store the list in an external file which is loaded at your application's starting point. This allows some flexibility if you forget anything or need to support later versions of a language without requiring a rebuild of your application.