# Check for SQL Keywords in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-injection, keyword

if i allow users to type in a textbox and then perform a search against my db, there is the potential for sql injection.  i could use regex, thats my first thought.  but i had a better idea.  why not see if what they typed has any SQL keywords in it.  Im using an SQL Server database, in an ASP.NET program with c#, i thought microsoft would have offered an easy solution to what i am talking about.  the best i can find is in this article:

[Is it a programmatic way to get SQL keywords (reserved words)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939731/is-it-a-programmatic-way-to-get-sql-keywords-reserved-words)

which is probably what ill end up doing, but my problem is i still have to type out the entire list of keywords, there is around a hundred.  sure i could be done by now instead of searching and asking this question.  but isnt there an easier way?  right now im going to:

1 Create a Hashset
2 add all the keywords to the hashset (cmon)
3 validate user input against the hashset

would love to see step 2 be made much easier,  any other suggestions about sql injections are also appreciated

Comment: I'd LIKE TO ADD my two cents, EXCEPT, I don't have the RIGHT change, would you take a CHECK?  I'd LIKE to SAVE you from HAVING to go to the bank, even IF the bank is CLOSE.      Considering that every upper case word above is a SQL keyword, I don't think this is a good approach....

Comment: A good approach would be to write a SQL stored procedure to take a text from the text box and perform the query...   Search for SQL injection and you'll find why creating a black-list of words isn't a good approach

Comment: ... iam using stored procs... no need to still check your saying?

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing the search text into a stored procedure and doing something like

```
WHERE search LIKE @inputParam
```

SQL will not allow injection to incur in the above fragment.

However, if you are building a string variable and then using EXEC @sql or sp_execute @SQL, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you would be better off avoiding the problem of checking for SQL keywords altogether by using [parameterized SQL](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).  Here's an example in C# (assuming you're using MS SQL Server):

```
using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] WHERE [SomeColumn] = @SomeValue", sqlconnection))
{
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeValue", strUsersSearchString);

    // use sqlcmd.ExecuteReader() here 
    // or whatever you normally would
}
```

Here's another example on MSDN. This one is using parameterized SQL to call a stored procedure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step3

Answer (score 0):

Use named parameters.  [Dapper-dot-net](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) makes it really easy to do this:

```
IEnumerable<Row> results = connection.Query<Row>("SELECT column FROM table WHERE title LIKE @query", new { query = "SEARCHTERM" });
```